# Bootstrap 3 inputs read-only in desktop mode but not on small devices

Tags: html, css, input, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having trouble with boostrap 3 causing deactivated/read-only inputs in desktop mode. Once you resize the browser window to a smaller size bootstrap activates the inputs to read-write. I am clueless why, of course they should be activated on all devices. Any help will be appreciated!

I tried having the `.form-group` arround the `.col-sm-x .col-md-x .col-lg-x` divs and a few other tweaks, the inputs only enable once they are completely outside of the `.col-sm-x .col-md-x .col-lg-x`, which destroys the layout. Is there any way of making this layout work in bs3?

Here's a fiddle, problem shows up in Safari, Firefox and Chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/Au5vM/3/

The form code looks like this, I am not so familiar with bs3 forms and grid, maybe someone might spot the problem:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputAcademicTitle">Degree</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAcademicTitle" placeholder="Titel" value="Resizing causes me to disable">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputFirstName">First name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Your first name" value="Resizing causes me to disable">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputLastName">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Your last name" value="Resizing causes me to disable">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputMotto">Comment</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="motto" placeholder="Your comment">textareas are not affected</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not disabled. The problem is that you're nesting `class="row"`. You can verify this by opening your browser's web tools, you'll see that the row containing the textarea overlaps the textboxes.

```
</div>
<div class="row">
```

should become

```
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
```

And

```
    </div>
</form>
```

should become

```
</form>
```

Comment: Ahw yes omg I am so blind, do 3-4 classes for each column cause blindness or what. Thank you!