# Bootstrap 3 - textarea is not editable on mobile screen (but editable on other screens)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

When using textareas in my application, the textarea become 'not editable' on mobile screens. On other screen sizes there are no problems. The input (text) fields are working fine on mobiles.

Why is the textarea not editable on mobiles? How can I make it editable again?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <form #f="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="gcid">GcId</label></div>
          <!-- <div class="col-xs-9"><input type="text" id="gcid" name="gcid" [(ngModel)]="gcid" #gcid="ngModel" class="form-control"></div> -->
          <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-10">
            <input type="text" id="gcid" name="gcid" [(ngModel)]="gcid" required class="form-control" #v_gcid="ngModel">
            <span *ngIf="!v_gcid.valid && v_gcid.touched" class="text-danger">GC mag niet leeg zijn. Vul een geldige GC code in. </span>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
        </div>
      </div>   
      ...     
      <div class="form-group col-xs-11">
        <div class="row">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea rows="3" id="description" name="description" [(ngModel)]="description" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-11">
        <div class="row">
        <label for="hint">Hint</label>
        <textarea rows="4" id="hint" name="hint" [(ngModel)]="hint" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: It could have something to do with the fact that your `<div class="row">` element that contains the textarea doesn't have an actual column (ex: `<div class="col-sm-12">` container, so it might throw things off).  This article gave me the idea: [Bootstrap 3 inputs read-only in desktop mode but not on small devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780004/bootstrap-3-inputs-read-only-in-desktop-mode-but-not-on-small-devices)

Comment: A "work-around" might be to see if adding `contenteditable="true"` to the textarea helps the cause.

Comment: @Cfnerd - can you put your (both) comments in an answer? Then I will mark it is the solution. The first comment was already sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it likely has something to do with the fact that your `<div class="row">` element that contains the `textarea` doesn't have the proper row/column/group nesting. Try restructuring the HTML like this and see if that helps the cause.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-11">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea rows="3" id="description" name="description" [(ngModel)]="description" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

As mentioned in my comment, this article gave me the idea: [Bootstrap 3 inputs read-only in desktop mode but not on small devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780004/bootstrap-3-inputs-read-only-in-desktop-mode-but-not-on-small-devices).

You could also try adding the `contenteditable="true"` attribute to the `textarea` to see if that works.  It shouldn't need it, but might help force the mobile screen to do what is needed.